# Selenium webdriver render html directly

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Rather than using

```
webdriver.get(url)
```

Can Selenium render a webpage directly from markup?

```
webdriver.render( html )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript executor to inject markup into a browser